# Reading user defaults with swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a few buttons that set a userdefault to different integers. How would i be able to say "if the userdealts = a specific integer{code}

Here its the code that sets the userdefault:

```
@IBAction func one(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    defaults1.set(1, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost one was selected")
}

@IBAction func two(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    defaults1.set(2, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost two was selected")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 1 {
  // do something
}

if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 2 {
  // do something
}
```

**Updates regarding to matt's comment (Use optional binding to handle if integer key doesn't exist):**

```
if let sphereKey = defaults1.object(forKey: "Sphere") {
  if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 1 {
    // do something
  }

  if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 2 {
    // do something
  }
} else {
  print("UserDefault Key 'Sphere' doesn't exist")
}
```

**or check if not nil (would be better cause in your case you won't use `sphereKey` from the optional binding above):**

```
if defaults1.object(forKey: "Sphere") != nil {
  if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 1 {
    // do something
  }

  if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 2 {
    // do something
  }
} else {
  print("UserDefault Key 'Sphere' doesn't exist")
}
```

Comment: yeah, sry wrote faster than I was thinking xD

Comment: it's `forKey`, not `forkey` - this is key-value coding, not a cafeteria

Comment: The real problem with this answer is that `integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 0` will return `true` even if the key is not even present in User Defaults at all. The OP might not want that to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the Hint @matt. You are totally right. Updated my answer

Comment: Would any of you know the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143183/working-with-skspritenodes-and-textures

Comment: I used your original code and it works beautifully, however when the app is launched for the first time ("Sphere" is nil) now image is shown at all. I tried to use the code that @matt wrote but still no image shows

Comment: if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == nil! {
            Ghost = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ghost2")

        }

Answer (score 1):

You should either use a `switch` or `if, else if` or `if - else` if you only have two values. To get the value, simply `defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere")`:

**Switch:**

```
switch defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") {
case 1:
    // 1
case 2:
    // 2
default:
    break
}
```

**if - else if:**

```
if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 1{
    // 1
}
else if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 2{
    // 2
}
```

**If you only have two values:**

```
if defaults1.integer(forKey: "Sphere") == 1{
   // 1
}
else{
   // 2
}
```

Comment: Do you know the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143183/working-with-skspritenodes-and-textures